# Random mac address generator in python

Tags: python, random

I am fairly new to python and was looking for solutions to generate random MAC addresses when I found this:

```
':'.join('%02x'%random.randint(0,255) for x in range(6))
```

what I am trying to understand is the use of `'%02x'%` in the code. Is it related to how mac addresses are represented which is a 48 bit hexadecimal value separated by `:`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

`'%02x'` is a format string for specifying a zero-filled two-digits hexadecimal number.

`'%02x' % number` will create the actual string with the number in such format.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't understand a list comprehension then the best tactic is to unwind it.

```
myhexdigits = []
for x in range(6):
    # x will be set to the values 0 to 5
    a = random.randint(0,255)
    # a will be some 8-bit quantity
    hex = '%02x' % a
    # hex will be 2 hexadecimal digits with a leading 0 if necessary
    # you need 2 hexadecimal digits to represent 8 bits
    myhexdigits.append(hex)
    # save for after the loop ends
print (':'.join(myhexdigits))
# using : as the delimiter, join the 2-digit hex strings together into
# a single string
```